# How to arrange multiple canvas?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to arrange multiple canvas on a screen for my phonegap mobile apps.Here i am using gridview to arrange canvas, but i get all the canvas attached. I want to have fixed gap between these canvas.
I have done by following:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b" style="width:100%;">
<div class="ui-block-a"><canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%"      style="background: #bababa;"></canvas></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #bababa;"></canvas></div>
<div class="ui-block-c"><canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #bababa;"></canvas></div>
<div class="ui-block-a"><canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #bababa;"></canvas></div>
<div class="ui-block-b"><canvas id="canvas" width="100%" height="100%" style="background: #bababa;"></canvas></div>
</div>
```

If you think ,using grid in this case, is a bad idea, please share a better logic to get the result.

Comment: Please clarify what you need. With this code, each block will receive 33.3% of total width since you're using gird system.

Comment: Actually i want to arrange these canvases with the fixed margin(top, left, right, bottom) among them, like buttons arranged in grid(ui-grid-b).

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6Gu2A/ ?